# GruntJS processing multiple directories

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed a bootstrap 3 environment via yeoman. It comes with a predefined gruntfile. Now i am completely new to Grunt and although most of it is working out of the box i need one (simple) change to the config. I have 2 language directories /en/ and /de/ with html files. The current gruntfile is setup to only process index.html in the root dir.

Looking at the build task and its jobs I get that I have to edit the configs of 'useminprepare', 'usemin' and 'htmlmin'. What I don't get is the syntax to include the 2 additional directories there.

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
  options: {
    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
  }
},
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/']
  }
},

[...]

htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
      src: '{,*/}*.html',
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},
```

and the build task:

```
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'copy:server',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent',
    'cssmin',
    'concat',
    'uglify',
    'copy',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read this https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin it was very usefull for me, if you still doesn't understand, later when i get home i will elaborate the answer.